# How to draw encapsulating border over image?

Tags: java, android

I have overridden image draw method to draw border on `AppCompatImageView`.

It works fine for some images but for some images it has some blank space above and below image as shown in picture below. I want to draw border exactly over image dimensions.

[image]

Below is code

```
private static final int PADDING = 8;
    private static final float STROKE_WIDTH = 8.0f;

    private Paint mBorderPaint;

   private void initBorderPaint() {
        mBorderPaint = new Paint();
        mBorderPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mBorderPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mBorderPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        mBorderPaint.setStrokeWidth(STROKE_WIDTH);
    }

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawRect(PADDING, PADDING, getWidth() - PADDING, getHeight() - PADDING, mBorderPaint);
}
```

Comment: Because you are getting alpha channel on that image. Am I correct? Is it alpha channel of source Image or Code Bug?

Comment: No there is alpha channel.

Comment: @GensaGames Actually, when I put image simply in res drawable-xhdpi folder border fits to image. How can I do this for the images picked from gallery or camera?

Comment: Never mind I have solved using android:adjustViewBounds="true" into image view